# Sort a list of Flutter widgets using my own compare function

Tags: sorting, flutter, dart

I'm building a TODO application using Flutter.
What I need to do is to sort tasks stored in `List` using my own compare method (completed tasks must be at the bottom).

The list I need to sort:

```
var taskWidgets = List<Widget>();
```

Elements of `taskWidgets` list are `TaskCard` class objects

```
class TaskCard extends StatefulWidget {
```

My compare method:

```
  int compareTasks(TaskCard a, TaskCard b) {
    if (a.state._checked == b.state._checked) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (a.state._checked && !b.state._checked) {
      return 1;
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

This is how I sort my list:

```
taskWidgets.sort(compareTasks);
```

After doing all that I get the following error:

```
type '(TaskCard, TaskCard) => int' is not a subtype of type '((Widget, Widget) => int)?'
```

I tried to change compare function

```
  int compareTasks(Widget a, Widget b) {
    if (a.state._checked == b.state._checked) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (a.state._checked && !b.state._checked) {
      return 1;
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

But then I got another error

```
lib/main.dart:98:11: Error: The getter 'state' isn't defined for the class 'Widget'.
 - 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../AppData/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'state'.
    if (a.state._checked == b.state._checked) {
```

So all in all, the question is:
How do I properly sort a List of TaskCard objects using my own compare function?

Comment: You should stick to this one only, but you need to pass the TaskCards as a param. Currently if you see the code, you do this **WRONG** ```taskWidgets.sort(compareTasks);```. Which is not correct. **RIGHT** ```taskWidgets.sort(compareTasks(TaskCard a, TaskCard b));```. If that makes sens to you

Comment: @Alok, this won't work: lib/main.dart:84:48: Error: Expected ',' before this.
        taskWidgets.sort(compareTasks(TaskCard a, TaskCard b));
                                               ^
lib/main.dart:84:60: Error: Expected ',' before this.
        taskWidgets.sort(compareTasks(TaskCard a, TaskCard b));
                                                           ^

Comment: lib/main.dart:84:48: Error: The getter 'a' isn't defined for the class '_MyHomePageState'.
 - '_MyHomePageState' is from 'package:flutter_app/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'a'.
        taskWidgets.sort(compareTasks(TaskCard a, TaskCard b));

Answer (score 2):

in the case you know all `taskWidgets` elements are of the type `TaskCard` you can change `taskWidgets` to be of type `List<TaskCard>` in order to make your first compare method work.

if you want to keep your list of type `List<Widget>`, you need to manualy check if your widgets are of type `Taskcard`, and take in to consideration the case in which they aren't:

```cs
int compareTasks(Widget a, Widget b) {
  if (!(a is TaskCard)) {
    return -1; // if a is not of type Taskcard, make it go before b
  }
  if (!(b is TaskCard)) {
    return 1; // if a is a TaskCard and b is not Taskcard, make b go before a
  }

  TaskCard taskA = a as TaskCard;
  TaskCard taskB = b as TaskCard;
  if (taskA.state._checked == taskB.state._checked) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (taskA.state._checked && !taskB.state._checked) {
    return 1;
  }
  return -1;
}
```